# Lognormal Distribution from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python

New to the site so hope you can help :-)

I'd like to create the log normal distribution from values which are columns in my data frame.

I have a dataframe with 4 columns and would like to create a new column outputting the lognormal cdf value for each row. Data looks like this:

```
Date        x        mu        sigma
01/02/2021  13          5         2
02/02/2021  15          4         2.1
03/02/2021  17          3.5       2.2
```

So I'd like a another column which takes the values in each row to calculate the lognormal cdf values. I.e. in excel terms it would be: lognorm.dist(x, mu, std, 1).

I found the below code which yields the correct values but I'm struggling to edit it to work off my data.

```
    from math import exp
    from scipy import stats

    def lognorm_cdf(x, mu, sigma):
        shape  = sigma
        loc    = 0
        scale  = exp(mu)
        return stats.lognorm.cdf(x, shape, loc, scale)

    x      = 25
    mu     = 2.0785
    sigma  = 1.744
    p      = lognorm_cdf(x, mu, sigma)  #yields the expected 0.74341
```

Many thanks in advance.

AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your function and apply it using pandas:

```py
Date        x        mu        sigma
01/02/2021  13          5         2
02/02/2021  15          4         2.1
03/02/2021  17          3.5       2.2

from math import exp
from scipy import stats

def lognorm_cdf(x, mu, sigma):
    shape  = sigma
    loc    = 0
    scale  = exp(mu)
    return stats.lognorm.cdf(x, shape, loc, scale)

def pandas_log(row):
    return lognorm_cdf(row['x'], row['mu'], row['sigma'])


# your dataframe:
df['log'] = df.apply(pandas_log, axis=1)
```

In your example:

```
data = [[13, 5, 2],[15,4,2.1],[17,3.5,2.2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'mu', 'sigma'])
df['log'] = df.apply(pandas_log, axis=1)
print(df)

    x   mu  sigma       log
0  13  5.0    2.0  0.111702
1  15  4.0    2.1  0.269207
2  17  3.5    2.2  0.380913
```

The `apply` method is used like a map function in python, and you can apply it over each axis (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

EDIT:
sometimes it is faster to perform calculations in vecotrized form. The apply function can be seen as an iteration over each row. To use the vector you need to import numpy.

```
import numpy as np
df['log'] = stats.lognorm.cdf(df.x, df.sigma, 0, np.exp(df.mu))
print(df)
      x   mu  sigma       log
0  13.0  5.0    2.0  0.111702
1  15.0  4.0    2.1  0.269207
2  17.0  3.5    2.2  0.380913
```

With larger datasets this method is possibly faster.

---

**New to the site so hope you can help :-)**

*Please be aware that you can select an answer (it does not have to be this one) as useful and you can accept answers so that others will know that this question probably does not need more attention.*